# Arbitrary and nonsigular displacement vector field

Tags: vector-fields

What does it mean that a displacement vector field is arbitrary and non singular?

kind regards

[Context of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9hf2.png)

Comment: Please give more context. Where did you find this statement?

Comment: Hello @DietrichBurde, thank you for your quick response, I have added the note from wich my question arose. I hope this sheads some light on the context.

Comment: All right, I added "vector field", since an "arbitrary field" is a different notion from abstract algebra.